# SQL Division Operator and implementation in Mysql

Tags: mysql

In a database i have some cars that are rented by customers. I want to find the cars that were rented by All Customers, and display their PlateNr. In other words i want to make SQL Division in MySql.
My Database is like this:

**Customer**

`ID,Name
1 , John
2 , Scott`

**Car**

`PlateNr,Colour
1111 , red
2222 , black`

**Rents**

`ID , PlateNr , Date
1,    1111,     2010-01-01
1,    1111,     2010-02-01
2,    1111,     2010-03-02
2,    2222,     2010-01-02`

Following some instructions i have the following query, but it doesn't work to find the car that was rented by all customers (correct result should be Platenr=1111). What is wrong with the query?

```
SELECT PlateNr
FROM rents as R1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT car.PlateNr 
    FROM car
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT rents.PlateNr
        FROM rents
        WHERE rents.PlateNr=R1.PlateNr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this query as:

```
SELECT PlateNr
FROM Rents
GROUP BY PlateNr
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer);
```

In plain English, this says to find all plates whose distinct count of renting customers matches the total number of customers.  I assume here that `ID` is a unique column in the `Customers` table.